# how to add 57x57 and 72x72 icons for an app that runs on iPhone and iPad (and iPod)

Tags: ios, ipad, png

My app works great on iPhone, but I enabled the iPad build, and now get a warning:
iPad: Icon.png: icon dimensions 57x57 don't meet the size requirements.  must be 72x72

Answer (score 0):

Are you making separate iPhone and iPad builds, instead of one universal build? Or is Apple's error message just less than helpful?

Your current icon is most likely named `Icon.png`. You can add one named `Icon-72.png` for the 72x72 size, or you can use the `CFBundleIconFiles` key in your Info.plist to specify a list of icon files for the various sizes. See [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BuildTimeConfiguration/BuildTimeConfiguration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW1) for more details.